# Using two networks for different things

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing

Is it possible to have two networks connected to my laptop?

At work, I have access to two networks, one I need to use for emails, internet, etc.
There is a second that I connect to to use certain programs, because the first network blocks certain ports.

What I need is to be connected to both, and for my computer to know to use connectionB for these programs and connectionA for everything else.

So I want to be able to open the internet using connectionA while having the program open using connectionB

Comment: On Windows? Are you already connected to both networks? Are you using two network adapters? If you are using wireless adapters, ****maybe**** you can assign different network profiles (private, public) to each network and block certain kind of traffic to flow through each network profile using the Windows Firewall.

Comment: Can you give examples of the things you want to access via your dongle - the bypassing network connection?  The ease of this is a bit depending on where you want to get to.

Comment: If you are using Linux, it is very easy to configure the system whichever way it pleases you, there is a trick to do this even on a per-application basis. Mac OS is more restrictive, and it even has no policy routing, but you can bind certain applications to a given interface of your choice (ssh, for instance). In Windows, all I am aware of is configuring your routing table on a per-destination basis.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use two networks, but you will need some manual setup (in cmd) to **route** the trafic to one or another.

Choose start then type `cmd` and enter

First things first, you will need to understand your configuration, to achieve this, type

```
route print
```

Use right click, and choose/mark/select (or something alike) select all the text press enter to copy. Them past it in a new notepad window or some other text editor

Repeat this step with the another network attached.

Remember to note also wich text is from what network.

The most fundamental lines are that following the 'Active routes:' specially the value under gateway.

The gateway server is the primary server that your computer is attached to, it is the server that helps out when your computer needs to reach any other service/website/etc.

Well this is the end of a first step.

The second one will need your intervention in a more active way:

You will need to discover, and note down, All IP addresses that you need to access by one network or the another, to achieve this, you may need to type:

```
ping WEB.SITE.YOU.NEED.COM
```

And note down the IP address to them, it's also a good idea to repeat this command within some minutes to make sure that this address isn't changing.

Another way could be talk to your network administrator to get his/her help with this.

As soon you have all this IP addresses, you should try, plugging in both networks, and type:

```
route print
```

one last time

Now your first lines after that 'active routes' should be compared to your notepad notes, the gateway responsible by your very first 0.0.0.0 route is your primary connection, so you do not need to take any actions to use anything that need this connection.

To each service that you need that is only accessible by the another net/route you will type

```
route add <IP_ADDRESS_OF_SERVICE> MASK 255.255.255.0 <GATEWAY> metric 9
```

Where gateway is the server from **the non primary one**

Then you already can test if this service is accessible.

To know more, take a look at:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779122(v=ws.10).aspx

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/